# Select box option not show selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy or move one select box item to another select box. The problem is that when one or more items are moved from the first box to the second, it should be selected. But it's not working.

My Code

```
function SelectMoveRows(SS1,SS2)
{


    var SelID='';
    var SelText='';
    var SelText2='';
    // Move rows from SS1 to SS2 from bottom to top
    for (i=SS1.options.length - 1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (SS1.options[i].selected == true)
        {
            SelID=SS1.options[i].value;
            SelText=SS1.options[i].text;
            SelText2=SS1.options[i].attr("selected");

            var newRow = new Option(SelText,SelID,SelText2);
            SS2.options[SS2.length]=newRow;
            SS1.options[i]=null;
        }
    }
    SelectSort(SS2);
}
```

Then I use

```
   SelText2=SS1.options[i].attr("selected");
```

But it's not working. If I use:

```
SelText2=SS1.options[i].select=true;
```

then option looks like:

```
<option value="3" selected="">Delivery</option>
```

But it should be:

```
<option value="3" selected="selected">Delivery</option>
```

Comment: make a fiddle of your code .... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `SelText2=SS1.options[i].attr("selected");` why would that work? You're trying to use a jQuery method (`attr('selected')`, which is a *getter*, it retrieves the value of the attribute), and you're chaining it to a DOM node, which has no access to jQuery methods anyway. Did you look at your browser's JavaScript console (press 'F12', if not)? And what's the relevant HTML to go along with this JavaScript? (You don't appear to be using jQuery, you'd probably be best off removing that tag, unless you're using it elsewhere and a jQuery solution is welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

In the option tag, the attribute selected doesn't need a value:

```
<option value="3" selected>Delivery</option>
```

is the same as

```
<option value="3" selected="selected">Delivery</option>
```

check it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/n99L2xhv/1/

Answer (score 0):

you should use .prop not .attr

e.g.

```
SelText2=SS1.options[i].prop("selected", true);
```

for reference: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

---

Update I would go about doing this as follows;

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>

$("#select1").change(function(){
    $("#select1 option:selected").each(function() {
        var option = $(this);
        $("#select2").append(option);
        $("#select1").remove(option);
    });
});
```

This will shift the selected option from Select 1 to Select 2 when it is chosen.

Comment: And why? Any reference?

Comment: `SS1.options[i]` is not a jquery object

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by David Thomas in the comments, `.attr()` is not a valid method on a select element; It is a method on a jQuery object, which you don't have.

You could just pass `true` as the parameter to the `Option` constructor, and the third parameter is really the `defaultSelected` property, while the fourth paramter is the `selected` property.

```
for (var i = SS1.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var option = SS1.options[i];
    if (option.selected) {
        SS2.add(new Option(option.text, option.value, false, true));
        SS1.remove(i);
    }
}
```

You could use `option.selected` instead of `true`, but because of the if-statement, you know `option.selected` will always be `true`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0n49bzj/2/)